# Old Nvidia GPU and Linux

Tags: linux, nvidia, distributions, proprietary-drivers

TL;DR: Is there a way to get nvidia-304 driver to work with newer Linux kernels (on any distro) with some patches? Have you any suggestions about choosing a good distro?

I have recently fixed an old desktop computer a friend gave me. It has a very old Nvidia GeForce 6100 that needs the nvidia-304 legacy driver. As I am used to Linux distros (I have used Ubuntu, Debian, OpenSUSE and CentOS for years on my main computers and on my servers) I wanted to install one of them.
I have tried with several distros but it seems that Nvidia has discontinued the drivers I need.
New Linux kernels doesn't seem to be supported.
Nouveau doesn't support my GPU.
Debian 9 has the non-free Nvidia driver in its official repo but it doesn't work very well (with gnome all I can see after login is a black screen, while with KDE it seems to work but it can't play videos in any browser and it lags randomly).
Ubuntu 18.04 and OpenSUSE Leap 15 don't even have that driver in their repos and the official .run file from Nvidia doesn't work on their kernels.
Manjaro fails to start.
I haven't tried with Arch Linux yet but I think it won't work (because of the kernel version).

I am going to use this computer to program, so I don't need a lot of performance as far as graphics is concerned.

Has anyone tried to get that driver (nvidia-304) to work with not-too-old distros (newer Linux kernels)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by upgrading to a Nvidia GT710. It's not a good card but it is very cheap and is supported by the latest Nvidia drivers. As I do not intend to use my old PC to perform graphics-related tasks, I am satisfied with my upgrade.